# Make query in json with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, json

Exist any approach to make query in json using Javascript?

Particularly I have a json in a variable json into my code javascript, this json is a array of data, each data have 3 attributes 'name', 'city' and 'age', and I want to retrieve all the data who name is 'pepe'.

Also I want to retrieve all the data with diferent name. For example if I have 3 data in the json, two of them has the same name, I want to retrieve only two object, I will be agreeable with the count of the row with different name.

How can I do this?

Comment: is possible show part of your josn string to explain problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to parse your json string first:

```
var array = JSON.parse(yourString);
```

Then you can filter your array:

```
var matches = array.filter(function(x) { return x.name == 'pepe' });
```

This will give you a new array with only the matching elements. If you need the result as json again, you can convert it back like this:

```
var resultString = JSON.stringify(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

**In addition** you can use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) or [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) library as the following:

```
    var arr = [
        {
            name: 'pepe',
            city: 'first city',
            age : 19
        },
        {
            name: 'second name',
            city: 'second city',
            age : 19
        },
        {
            name: 'third name',
            city: 'third city',
            age : 19
        }
    ]
    _.find(arr, {name:'pepe'})
```

> Underscore: is a JavaScript library that provides a whole mess of
>   useful functional programming helpers without extending any built-in
>   objects.
>
> lodash: A JavaScript utility library delivering consistency,
>   modularity, performance, & extras.

Comment: Use underscore.js for what ?

Comment: Why using underscore.js, if es5 gives you functionality for this?

Comment: that may be related to the way you think, I for example starts always with one of this libraries.